# Download(copy?) a file from my res/raw folder to the default Android download location?

Tags: android

I am making a soundboard for practice and I want to give the user the ability to download the sound (that I have included in the app in the `res/raw` folder) onClick of a menu item but I can only find information about downloading from an internet url, not something that I already included in the apk.

What is the best way to do this? I would like to give them the option to save to an SD card also if this is possible. A point towards the correct class to use in the documentation would be great! I've been googling to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: This is quite easy, writing an answer just now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void saveResourceToFile() {
InputStream in = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
try {
    in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
    String downloadsDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
    String filename = "myfile.mp3"
    fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadsDirectoryPath + "/"+filename));

    final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    int count;
    while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        fout.write(data, 0, count);
    }
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
    if (fout != null) {
        fout.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like it's what I need -- WIll this download to the default downloads folder if there is no sd card on the phone? Or does getExternalStorageDirectory() just find whatever storage area they have set on their phone? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, It will 'download' to the downloads folder (which may vary), but this is just a basic example, and you may want to check if SD card is writable, etc. BTW, there is a complete code example at the android developers website [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29), which may be better than this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the `raw` but I did a similar thing in my app using the `assets` folder. My files are under the `assets/backgrounds` folder as you can probably guess from the code below.

You can modify this code and make it work for you (I know I will only have 4 files which is why I have `i` go from 0 to 4 but you can change this to whatever you want).

This code copies the file starting with `prefix_` (like prefix_1.png, prefix_2.png, etc) to my cache directory but you can obviously change the extension, the filename or the path you would like to save the assets to.

```
public static void copyAssets(final Context context, final String prefix) {
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        String filename = prefix + "_" + i.toString() + ".png";
        File f = new File(context.getCacheDir() + "/" + filename);
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }

        if (!f.exists())
            try {
                InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("backgrounds/" + filename);
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fos.write(buffer);
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception occurred while trying to load file from assets.", e.getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```