# Is it possible to download a zip file from an application without access to the Internet?

Tags: android

My Android application allows the user to download a zip file from the Internet. Someone can tell if it is possible to install a zip file from the application itself? Without access to the Internet. I was looking for an opportunity to do this for a long time, and already at a loss.

```
private void gotoact1(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId()) {


        case R.id.buttonDow:

            Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,         
                 Uri.parse("https://drive.google.com/file/d/16eu- 
                 2gI8c549rt6Ve04UIyDm3oeGAHeu/view?usp=sharing"));

            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


public void onClick(View view) {
    //requestNewInterstitial();
    clicked = view;
    {gotoact1(clicked); }
}
```

P.S. Thanks for the reply, I began to understand!
I added my zip file to the "raw" folder with the name "my.zip" and added the code (below), unfortunately the installation of the file on the phone did not happen, can you see my error?

```
private   void gotoact1(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case
                R.id.buttonDowN:
            saveResourceToFile();

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void saveResourceToFile() {
    InputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.signature);
        String downloadsDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        String filename = "my.zip";
        fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadsDirectoryPath + "/" + filename));

        final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "DownloadOne!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "DownloadTwo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (fout != null) {
            try {
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added Toast to the code and included DownloadTwo. Why is FileNotFoundException turned on? I still can not understand:(
Very embarrassed that I can not figure it out myself, sorry

> 2019-03-24 05:10:03.662 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/my.zip (Permission denied)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:308)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:238)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:180)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.Main4.saveResourceToFile(Main4.java:57)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.Main4.gotoact1(Main4.java:42)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.Main4.onClick(Main4.java:33)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6648)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6620)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:787)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.663 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26167)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.664 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.664 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.664 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.664 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7536)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.664 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.664 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.664 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.690 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl: asyncReportData com.example.myapplication,2,1,1,0 interval=80
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.706 5385-5412/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.740 5385-5412/com.example.myapplication D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.741 5385-5412/com.example.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
>   2019-03-24 05:10:03.940 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl: asyncReportData com.example.myapplication,2,1,2,0 interval=330
>   2019-03-24 05:10:05.332 5385-5385/com.example.myapplication D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=5385
>   2019-03-24 05:10:05.696 5385-5412/com.example.myapplication W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7abd817010 disconnect failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it solved by copying the zip file from the raw folder of your app to the Android Download folder?

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817856/downloadcopy-a-file-from-my-res-raw-folder-to-the-default-android-download-lo) is similar.

However, you will need to add permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also in my case I had to fix the following part of the answer.
Add: `+ "/"`

```
fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadsDirectoryPath　+ "/" + filename));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I began to understand!
I added my zip file to the raw folder with the name "my.zip" and added the code (in the post), unfortunately, the installation of the file on the phone did not happen, do you see my error?

Comment: If the app does not crash and Logcat does not show an error, it may have succeeded. There is no change in UI upon success. In my case, I was able to check the target file in File Manager application (Local> Internal Storage> Download).

exsample:
`
in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my);
...
String filename = "my.zip"
`

If implemented in your app, you may need to add a UI, such as displaying Toast on success.

Comment: I am grateful for your advice, thanks to Toast I noticed that an exception has occurred. I edited my second attempt and made sure that the file was not found. I hope this is a small mistake (

Comment: I see 'Permission denied' in the log.
You may need to make sure that you really have Permission.
Settings > Apps&notifications > App info > your app name > Permissions > Storage is On?
If it is off please turn it on and try it.

Please check with [RuntimePermission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) when implementing.

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you!